# how to remove cumulative pairs from pandas dataframe keeping only one of it

Tags: python, pandas

I'm translating some code from R to python. I want to remove pairs with the same id, keeping only one of them in the data frame.

Also I can't drop duplicates by 'id' as it's possible that I have multiple combination for same "id" which might not be cumulative pairs
example:

```
       id                 value.x      value.y 
1: 100057    38953993985    38993095846 
2: 100057   38993095845    38953993985  
3: 100057    38993095845    38993095846
4. 100057   38993095846    38953993985
```

This is the R code:

```
res <- df[df[, .I[1], by = list(pmin(value.x, value.y), pmax(value.x, value.y))]$V1]
```

Input df looks like this:

```
> head(df)

       id      value.x      value.y 
1: 100011 38989281716 38996868028   
2: 100011 38996868028 38989281716  
3: 100019 38916115350 38994231881  
4: 100019 38994231881 38916115350 
5: 100031 38911588267 38993358322
6: 100031 38993358322 38911588267
```

Output should be

```
> head(res)

       id      value.x      value.y 
1: 100011 38989281716 38996868028 
2: 100019 38916115350 38994231881  
3: 100031 38911588267 38993358322
```

Comment: Use `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id'], keep='first')`.

Comment: Which one do you have to keep?

Comment: value_x - value_y combination and not other way round
exa : I will keep
```
       id      value.x      value.y 
1: 100011 38989281716 38996868028
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you try this:

```
df['value'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['value.x'].astype(str) +x['value.y'].astype(str) if x['value.x']>x['value.y'] else  x['value.y'].astype(str) +x['value.x'].astype(str) , axis = 1)
df.drop_duplicates(subset='value', keep='first', inplace=True)
```

---

```
       id      value.x      value.y
0  100011  38989281716  38996868028
1  100011  38996868028  38989281716
2  100019  38916115350  38994231881
3  100019  38994231881  38916115350
4  100031  38911588267  38993358322
5  100031  38993358322  38911588267
       id      value.x      value.y                   value
0  100011  38989281716  38996868028  3899686802838989281716
2  100019  38916115350  38994231881  3899423188138916115350
4  100031  38911588267  38993358322  3899335832238911588267
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you you want to preserve the first value, you can either

```
# use groupby
df.sort_values('id').groupby('id').first()
```

or you can try to drop duplicates as:

```
df.dort_values('id').drop_duplicates(subset=['id'], keep='first')
```

Groupby is probably an overkill since you aren't performing any aggregation so for speed and simplicity, i would suggest the second option

Comment: No, there might be a chance that I have mutiple combination for same "id" which might not be cumulative pairs
example

```
       id                 value.x      value.y 
1: 100057    38953993985    38993095846 
2: 100057   38993095845    38953993985  
3: 100057    38993095845    38993095846
4. 100057   38993095846    38953993985
```

Comment: Can you edit this into the question. It is hard to read it as a comment.

Comment: I added same comment in question now

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are rather looking to remove duplicate rows of IDs. And you want to retain the first entry, and remove the rest entries for that ID.

You can use

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='id', keep='first', inplace=True)
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: No, I can't drop by id as there are chances that multiple pairs under same id can exists which are not cumulative. Added such example in dataframe